# Seed error in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-seeding

I am facing seeding issue.My `AddressessTableSeeder.php` file is like below

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AddressessTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Address::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) 
        {
            $u->users()->save(factory(App\User::class)->make());
        });
    }
}
```

My `Address.php` file is like below

```
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name', 'address','mobile_no','image','email'];

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

I am getting error like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `associate` and create the user before associating so you can get the id before saving it

```
factory(App\Address::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) 
{
    $u->users()->associate(factory(App\User::class)->create())->save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Joshua Kisubi. I am getting new error after using your code. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MajvG.png

Comment: using users() instead of user() `$u->users()->associate(factory(App\User::class)->create())->save();`

Comment: oi install PDO, how have you been running laravel code

Comment: `how have you been running laravel code` What does it mean ? @Joshua Kisubi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160647/discussion-between-joshua-kisubi-and-abu-abu).